# How to set the condition if there is no data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

i want search box where the user can search the name from database.

So the main idea is to find the name if it is available, or if it not available than it should show it is not available and when the user did input data is null it should not do anything.

**PHP File** --

```
// url- "/userdata/mydata"
public function mydataAction($id) {
        //$id the data which is input by the user

    $paramss = array('hosts' => array('localhost:9200'));
    $client = new Elasticsearch\Client($paramss); //connect with database

    if (strlen($id) > 0) {
        // if the input charactar is more than 1       

        $params = array();
        // condition of seach in the elasticsearch by $id
        // which is working fine
        );

        // find the input result
        $esresult = $client->search($params);
        print_r($esresult);
    } else {
        // if the input data is less than one  or 0
        echo "no result";
    }

    return new Response("ok");
}
```

**html---**

```
<form action="/userdata/mydata/+" {{id}} method="post"> // i think i am not passing the input data as a id properly
<label><input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="callServer()"></label>

     </form>
```

**Script ---**

```
<script>
    function callServer() {
        var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var url = '/userdata/mydata/' + x;
        $.ajax({url: url, type: 'POST', })
                .done(function () {

                });
    }
</script>
```

Do anyone knows how can i fix this problem.

I want to make a simple search box  which find the name only if available otherwise shows it is not available.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Maybe you can do the judgement in the front-end using `if(x)` then do the ajax post.

Comment: In php, you can use `if(empty($id))` to test if $id is empty

Comment: Looks like you have a skelton with no meat on it. In other words it looks like you want someone here to code this funtionality for you. **SO is not a free coding site** Please read [The tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What kind of array is $param returning? Maybe you can loop through it, parsing it in a JS array, then doing a client-side check

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your kind answer, actually i have tried different things to make it work, but somehow nothing is working for me, i need some suggestion to solve this, i don't want that you do coding for me, thanks :)

Comment: @lockedz can you kindly give me a simple example

Comment: In that case its off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP:
Use `"echo json_encode($esresult);"` instead of `"print_r($esresult);"`

JS:

```
.done(function (result) {
    if(result=='no results'){
       alert('No results');
     } else {
       jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
       //do something you your results
     }
});
```